# Retrieving custom fields via QueryResult

Tags: soql, api, c#

I'm new to using SOQL and QueryResult. I'm using C# and the sample code from here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_walk_through_code.htm

I'm trying to understand how to retrieve custom fields in the querySample() method. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Mark, the link you have in your question already has sample queries.. have you tried those samples ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the custom field name(s) to the query String and if the Enterprise WSDL was extracted from the org after the custom field was added the relevant getter method will already be present; if it wasn't you can re-extract it and regenerate your C# code.

The changes to the method would then be (assuming the field is a text field called "MyCustomField"):

```
  private void querySample() {
      String soqlQuery = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, MyCustomField__c FROM Contact";
      try {
         QueryResult qr = connection.query(soqlQuery);
         boolean done = false;

         if (qr.getSize() > 0) {
            System.out.println("\nLogged-in user can see "
                  + qr.getRecords().length + " contact records.");

            while (!done) {
               System.out.println("");
               SObject[] records = qr.getRecords();
               for (int i = 0; i < records.length; ++i) {
                  Contact con = (Contact) records[i];
                  String fName = con.getFirstName();
                  String lName = con.getLastName();
                  String myCustomField = con.getMyCustomField__C();
                  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. I'd already modified the SOQL query as you suggest, but the equivalent of the con.getMyCustomField_C() method is not available to me. Note too that in the method code in the sample, the names are retrieved via FirstName and LastName properties on the Contact, not getFirstName() and getLastName() methods.

Comment: @MarkJones Oh I see now that the example is Java. Exactly what you get depends on choices made by the writer of the WSDL => C# tool. If you export the Enterprise WSDL after you have added your custom field it should appear somewhere in the new WSDL and if you then regenerate the C# code it should appear in that too. That's the whole idea of the Enterprise WSDL: classes and fields that exactly match your org are generated.

Comment: Ah ok cool - that makes sense. I think I've used some more generic WSDL which doesn't contain the custom fields. Many thanks for your help...

Comment: @MarkJones Salesforce provide the "Partner WSDL" which keeps everything generic. This is good if the org changes a lot, but the client gets no compile-time checking because things like fields are all based on string keyed maps. The "Enterprise WSDL" gives the client explicit names and types to compile against at the cost of having to be updated every time a field or object you want to access is added.